# disable "empty" in caja file manager when showing last folder

Tags: xubuntu, filemanager, caja

I'm trying to use the Caja file manager with the tree view.  I like the Windows explorer-style with a left window where I can choose the folders and a right window where I can see the files stored in the selected folder.

In tree view I can expand the folders in the left window.  When I select the last folder (no sub folder) I have an arrow before the name of the folder and when I expand the folder there is still the word "empty" as "sub folder".  That is useless to me.

Can I disable that useless arrow before the folders name and the word "empty"?  I know that there is now a sub folder when there is no arrow before the folder.

Comment: Please provide a screnshot

Answer (score 0):

If you have looked and cannot find a way from within Caja to alter this behavior, then the answer is going to be slightly more complicated.  However, Caja is an open source project, so you do have two options:

1. Here is the [Caja project on Github](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja).  Fork it, take a look at it, and write a patch for this issue.
2. Create an issue for this behavior in the [Caja GitHub Issues page](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/issues).  **At the very least, you should do this**, because it will bring this issue to the attention of the developers.

It looks like the latest activity in the Issues page was 6 days ago, so at least you know it's being actively developed.  Good luck!